# HTML set image on browser tab

Tags: html, css, favicon

How do I set a little icon next to the website title on tabs in the web browser?

Comment: How can this be marked as duplicate if it preceded "How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website" by almost a year?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It's called a [Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon), have a read.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/myicon.ico"/>
```

You can use [this neat tool](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/) to generate cross-browser compatible Favicons.

Comment: I would only add, here's a nice online tool to generate crossbrowser compatible favicons based on existing bmp/png/gif/jpeg images: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/ The site at its own also contains good additional background information.

Answer (score 9):

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="ICON" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

Excellent tool for cross-browser favicon - http://www.convertico.com/

Comment: is indicating type attr necessary here ?

Comment: are both lines the same... ? or they should come together... ? or using one would suffice ? I would appreciate if you solve my confusion.