# How to insert logo with the title of a HTML page?

Tags: html, favicon

As stackoverflow.com has  logo with it's title, how it can be done for any usual site? Which code is needed for this?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Are you referring to the [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)?

Upload a 16x16px ico to your site, and link it in your `head` section.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

There are a multitude of sites that help you convert images into .ico format too. This is just the first one I saw on Google. http://www.favicon.cc/

Answer (score 9):

Yes you right and I just want to make it understandable for complete beginners.

1. Create favicon.ico file you want to be shown next to your url in browsers tab. You can do that online. I used http://www.prodraw.net/favicon/generator.php it worked juts fine.
2. Save generated ico file in your web site root directory /images (yourwebsite/images) under the name favicon.ico.
3. Copy this tag  `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />` and past it without any changes in between `<head>` opening and `</head>` closing tag.
4. Save changes in your html file and reload your browser.

Comment: A comment that might be useful to someone - if you don't call the favicon "favicon.ico" (e.g. you call it instead "my_favicon.ico"), it won't load. It MUST be called "favicon.ico".

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon). [They're easy to do](http://www.favicon.cc/).

Answer (score 0):

It's called a favicon. It is inserted like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.domain.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.domain.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Keep the picture file named "favicon.ico". You'll have to look online to get a .ico file generator.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem, but its actually a favicon.ico file that you can have. Google favicon.ico generator and either download premade favicons or make your own. And then after insert the following code:

inside the head tag.