# favicon won't show up in chrome but show up in other browsers like IE, Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

I have the html:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon_muse_me.ico">
```

on my website Muse Me (http://www.musememobile.com)
The favicon won't show up if I open it with Chrome.  It shows up in other Browsers.

The favicon showed up before in Chrome but then I changed it.

What should I do to make it show up in Chrome?

Comment: Does it show up if you simply add the .ico file to the root directory? (You may need to relaunch your browser to test fully)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML favicon wont show on google chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome)

Comment: interesting page https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the ICO file to the root directory as 'favicon.ico'.

Comment: **If renaming and refreshing doesn't work, try closing and reopening the browser**. I was like "what gives?" then closed/reopened the browser for a sanity check and baaaam ..there it was.

Comment: "Originally, the favicon was a file called favicon.ico placed in the root directory" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: ctrl-shift-r fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers disregard the favicon metatag, and just look for /favicon.ico.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not support animated favicons, and it doesn't look like anyone is interested in implementing it.

Original bug report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19731

Latest duplicate: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130062

Comment: Thanks for the answer I needed. I can declare only Opera works with my animated icon and IE, FF and Chrome don't/

Comment: And also FF. Make sure you clear the history of the browsers. So indeed only chrome doesn't work with animated icon. Strangely in my local machine it now shows also in chrome. But In the hosting server it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you declare a "type" for your link?  Also, you can try a rel of simply "icon" in addition.
Try this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon_muse_me.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon_muse_me.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

You could also try appending the domain to the image src as well:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.musememobile.com/images/favicon_muse_me.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.musememobile.com/images/favicon_muse_me.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

**UPDATE**
You could also try using a png for your favicon (obviously will need to have a png version to do this).  This is the approach I take with my own site and it looks fine in Chrome:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon_muse_me.png" />
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. The wired thing is in my local server, the favicon I used before will show up in the root page (only in the root page). But I already deleted it and changed to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's in `<head>` tag. It's kind of...'meta' info for the page.

```
<head>
<link href="//domain.com/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
```

I tried other options but this worked in Chrome for me

Answer (score 0):

What I have been using is the URI, witch you can find out at https://websemantics.uk/tools/image-to-data-uri-converter and just put it in the atrabute `href`.

For example this is a valid URI a favicon

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/png;base64,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">
```