# HTML favicon link tags not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I see the icon in Firefox but in Chrome it's missing; is there any problem in the HTML?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="icon" href="favicon.ico"  />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="Bookmark" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
```

Does the dimension of the file matters or not? My icon's dimension is 20 X 20.

Comment: if firefox is showing then no problem in html. I think cache is the problem!

Comment: @Ankit Ladhania Are you running from a local file or from a web server?

Comment: i'm running it on a local file

Comment: @Ankit Ladhania See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your favicon should be a 16x16 or 32x32 .ico file.
Place icons in the root directory of your site.
Link with:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Note: Chrome and IE require the image be 16x16 and **will not show favicons for local files**.
Make sure to clear the cache to test changes.

This was covered in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221292/local-file-website-favicon-works-in-firefox-not-in-chrome-or-safari-why).

Comment: I had favicon in img folder not in root, for me this was issue, move to root folder and fixed

Comment: use ctrl + f5 to refresh in chrome to see the change

Answer (score 1):

Try with `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">`.
Other reason can be caching.

Comment: Like I said it should be cache :)

Comment: Try to open your favicon.png in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Browser just caches previous version so just add
`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2">`

Answer (score 0):

**First** try clearing your cache. Cache sometimes problems alot and next try using `image/x-icon` as the type of that `<link>` :)

Add favicon in the root directory and check! :) This worked here: [favicon won't show up in chrome but show up in other browsers like IE, Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754613/favicon-wont-show-up-in-chrome-but-show-up-in-other-browsers-like-ie-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/x-icon" 
      href="img/favicon.ico">
```

ALL MAJOR BROWSER’S

Depending on the type of file you’re using one of the following is the standard way to add a favicon in well-built web browsers.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.example.com/image.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://www.example.com/image.gif">
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://www.example.com/image.ico">
```

Comment: why the same as of @goran stoyanov ??

Comment: i didnt see his answer,will post something different

Comment: @Ankit : see this [LINK](http://www.kevinleary.net/how-to-add-cross-browser-favicon-website/)

Comment: @AnkitLadhania i dont know whether the size would matter, but mostly used is 16px x 16px

Comment: @AnkitLadhania : check this step 1 : in this [LINK](http://www.joomladesigns.co.uk/Tutorials/Web-Design/How-Do-I-Change-The-Favicon.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm use only this: `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="here_your_favicon_address"/>`. Working everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="path/to/touchicon.png">
<link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon.png">
<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="path/to/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->
<!-- or, set /favicon.ico for IE10 win -->
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#D83434">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="path/to/tileicon.png">
```

A detailed tutorial, please click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css/understand-the-favicon.html).