# my page title icon became youtube

Tags: html, title

I am developing webpages using html 5. I've got the following code in one of my pages

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MY_VIDEO_DIR" height="320" width="480">   
</iframe>
```

Then, the icon beside the page title became YouTube. How would I remove this auto-generated icon?

Thx.

Comment: Do you have any icon of your website?

Comment: Refer this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-for-a-website

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change icon for your website you can use the following:-

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```