# Naming Conseqences in the browser

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a application named as Faculty management done in asp.net with c#,I need a title FACULTY to be displayed in top of the browser,is there any code for that or any settings present in the browser?
[image]

Like here Google i want the name Faculty.How to do this..?

Comment: Just update the title tag inside your html.

Comment: Are you using a master page?

Comment: you need to set page tile to show in brower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a master page, you have to set the title in the @Page directive in the content page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/FacultyMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Title="Faculty" %>
```

If you're on a standard page, you can just set the title in the HTML:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Faculty</title>
    ...
</head>
```

To add an icon, you can use the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-for-a-website):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: also i need a faculty symbol for that

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to a StackOverflow question which answers your needs.