# How can I add a tab icon?

Tags: html, icons

I've tried adding a tab icon to my webpage, I've looked at other pages, but couldn't get any answers why my icon wasn't working. I'm new to coding so please make your answers simple.

**Here is my code:**

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href=favicon.ico>
</head>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website)

Comment: Usually, you have to Ctrl+F5 your page.

Comment: did you add cdn..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following inside the `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/favicon/favicon.ico">
```

and make sure that the `favicon.ico` is present in `/path/to/favicon/`

Comment: Everything is in the same folder

Comment: if every thing is setted right, then verify that the `favicon` is a png file. or recreate a PNG file, then change its extension to `ico`