# I don't know where to put this code

Tags: html, favicon, osclass

I'm using this site to make a favicon https://realfavicongenerator.net , after i download the favicon and put it in root of my site, where do i put this?

```html
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

what file exactly. Im using osclass

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website)

Answer (score 0):

Put like this:

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <title>Oxygen - One Page HTML Template | Themeum</title>
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link id="css-preset" href="css/presets/preset1.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
      <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
      <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
      </head>
      <!--/head-->

      <body>
      </body>
      </html>
```