# HTML-How to add an Icon logo in browser

Tags: html, icons, favicon

I'm building a website and i want to add a small icon logo to the title bar of the browser.
Where i have to place the code?
I tried before the head but nothing happens

Comment: Here is a good reference for you [How to add favicon for a website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35625707/8644764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logo on title bar is called favicon. To include a favicon in your website you just need to provide the link to your icon inside your  tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
    <link rel = "icon" type = "image/png" href = "/icon.png">
    <!-- For apple devices -->
    <link rel = "apple-touch-icon" type = "image/png" href = "/icon.png"/>
  </head> 
</html>
```

By using this you can include your icon in the title bar of your website. The extension of your icon should be .png for better visibility and convert your png to .ico extension for more support.

Comment: CORRECTION: I tested this in Chrome and it worked. No icon showed up in Edge or Internet Explorer using this code.

Comment: I also was able to get an ico to work in chrome, but not ie or edge.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!