# What is the coding for fav icon in a website?

Tags: html

What is the coding for fav icon in a website ?

I need whole coding for fav icon of a website

Comment: Please be more specific. You can attach some screenshot. It's not clear what exactly are you asking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website)

Comment: I am guessing you need to add favicon to a static HTML page.. then please refer to this SOF link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page

Answer (score 1):

You should probably research stuff before asking such a question (this is a basic element of ALL websites and is VERY easy to find on the net and in pages by inspecting them via the console) - but answer is that its an .ico file extension and place it in the root of your document (in the same directory as your index.html or equivalent.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

There are numerous examples of this on the net and tehere are sites that will take a 16 x 16 png and convert it into the ico file extension for you to download and use.