# Why is my icon not showing in HTML website?

Tags: html

I am not able to see the icon beside the title of the webpage...Why is that?

Here is the line of code where I have put it and both the icon and the HTML file are in the same directory -

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Try `/favicon.ico` instad of just `favicon.ico`

Comment: You should put this line inside your `head` tag, is it the case?

Comment: You don't need `type="image/x-icon"`.

Comment: You can add full url to icon. And in case that shows old icon, add version. `favicon.ico?v=1`

Comment: I tried /favicon.io it still doesn't work
It  is in the head tag
When I remove type="image/x-icon" it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website) and have a look at the code below.

```
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ext">
```

Comment: Your contributions are welcome, but please note that answering questions that already have answers on Stack Overflow (like this) is against the guidelines.  See the "answer well-asked questions" section of  [answer]. Your answer could even get downvoted, even if it is correct! Instead you should flag the question as a duplicate and include the link there, instead of adding it in another answer.