# Is there any way to add a logo of the GUI application made by using Eel Python?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, icons, eel

I am building an GUI application by using Eel Python. The first thing I noticed that -
By default the application has chrome icon that I have to change it. But I didn't find any method to do it. So Is their any way to change the icon of the application?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="path_to_icon">
```

to the head tag in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Just use the normal way to add an icon in html, this automatically adds the Icon to your Eel application.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35625707) Answer here.