# Pug.js Chrome Tab Icon

Tags: pug

I am new to pug. I founded pug in a youtube video in how to make a dashboard. I am currently a student and confused to how use the tab icon in pug.
By tab icon I meant the image in the red circle.
[image: tab icon]

If you know how to do it , please do answer to this question :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website)

Comment: This works now! Thanks for replying! :D