# How can I set a favicon for a directory browsing page on iis?

Tags: windows, iis, themes, customization, favicon

On IIS in a Windows VM Server, I have a "site" that just points to a folder with directory browsing enabled, so users can view the files of the folder easily from their browser. Can I somehow set a "favicon" to that IIS page? You know, the little icon that shows up in the browser tab?

Answer (score 1):

Do you think the website directory browsing page of the following style is too monotonous?

[image]

If you want to set a "favicon" for each directory item in the directory browsing page, this link may help you: [Get nice looking directory listings for your IIS website with DirectoryListingModule](https://mvolo.com/get-nice-looking-directory-listings-for-your-iis-website-with-directorylistingmodule/)

Comment: I don't mean for a little icon to show up next to each item. Yes it's kinda crap looking but it's fine. By "favicon" I mean the actual favicon of the page, like, the icon you see on the tab on the browser at the top.

Comment: Do you mean the "icon" like the one I marked? [sample image](https://imgur.com/a/OaIWERA)

Comment: Yes, exactly that. The little icon on the browser tab.

Comment: Because by default it has that little circle symbol thing which really doesn't look great

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the "favicon" for the page, just add the following code to the  element:

`<link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.png">`

For details, please refer to: [How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website)